# How to delete an image you have append?

Tags: javascript

I am new at JavaScript and want to know how to delete an image that you have append?

The error message is: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

```
let myCars = new Array();
let positionTop = 100;


function addCar(){
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "/res/Car.png";

    img.style.position = "absolute";
    img.style.top = positionTop + "px";
    img.style.left = "25px";
    positionTop += 100;

    myCars.push(img);

    document.getElementById("car").appendChild(img);
}


function deleteCar(){
    document.getElementById(myCars[myCars.length - 1]).remove; // TypeError
    myCars.splice(myCars.length - 1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already pushed the whole image element inside the `myCars` array.

So, you can directly remove the `image` from it as it has the reference of the image.

```
function deleteCar(){
    myCars[myCars.length - 1].remove();
    myCars.splice(myCars.length - 1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your image does not have an id so you can select the image directly and delete it.

`document.getElementById(myCars[myCars.length - 1])` is an invalid syntax because `myCars` is a list of DOM elements. If you access `myCars[index]` it will return a DOM element so `document.getElementById(myCars[myCars.length - 1])` will be an invalid syntax. Since `myCars[myCars.length - 1]` already return a DOM element, you can simpley call `remove()` on the same node, just like `myCars[myCars.length - 1].remove();`

```js
let myCars = new Array();
let positionTop = 100;

function addCar() {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "/res/Car.png";
  img.style.position = "absolute";
  img.style.top = positionTop + "px";
  img.style.left = "25px";
  positionTop += 100;

  myCars.push(img);

  document.getElementById("car").appendChild(img);
}

function deleteCar() {
  myCars[myCars.length - 1].remove();
  myCars.splice(myCars.length - 1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="car"></div>
<button onclick="addCar()">Add Car</button>
<button onclick="deleteCar()">Delete Car</button>
```